# how to use vDSP_vswmax to get the maximum value in a sliding window?

Tags: ios, swift, math, signal-processing, vdsp

I tried and tried to get the maximas but I Cant, the array is big like this:

```
  var testBuff = [Float](repeating: 0.0,
                           count: Int(testArr.count))
    var maxSamplesBuffer = [Float](repeating: 0.0,
                                   count: testArr.count)

vDSP_vabs(testArr, 1, &testBuff, 1, vDSP_Length(testArr.count));//get absolute value array


    vDSP_vswmax(testBuff, 1, &maxSamplesBuffer, 1, vDSP_Length(20) , vDSP_Length(30))//Returns: self[i] = max(a[i ..< i+windowLength])
```

testArr is [422848] samples containing floats.
I can get the maximas for small arrays but when it gets big i have trouble.

Comment: After trying my best to make this function work for me I concluded that it produces incorrect values and submitted a radar FB8989475. I think that it's not working as intended.